# How do you stack rows under a specific column in pandas without using pd.melt?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, melt

I'm trying to pivot this table so that columns 1-8 are stacked under column 0. Basically, I want to put this into tableau eventually so I want to have workable data. I'm planning on dropping the "None" values after I pivot the table.
[image]

I've tried using pd.melt but kept getting errors.

Comment: "kept getting errors" – what errors? With what code?

Answer (score 0):

You should, in fact, use pd.melt. Check your syntax, below is an example:

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['col0'], value_vars=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8'], var_name='variable', value_name='value')
```